# Changing a byte in a .wav file header while creating an output file

Tags: c, wav

I'm trying to change the bytes corresponding to file size in the header of a .wav file, which are the 4th and 40th bytes. Currently, I am copying the entire header to a buffer, attempting to edit it there and then writing it to a destination file, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv []){

    int delay = atoi(argv[1]);
    FILE * source = fopen(argv[2], "rb");
    FILE * destination = fopen(argv[3], "wb");

    void * header = malloc(44); // size of a wav file header
    fread(header, sizeof(header), 1, source);

    // my attempt at changing the 4nd and 40th bytes
    sizeptr1 = (unsigned int *)(header + 4);
    sizeptr2 = (unsigned int *)(header + 40);
    *sizeptr1 = *sizeptr1 + delay;
    *sizeptr2 = *sizeptr2 + delay
    fwrite(header, sizeof(header), 1, destination);

    return 0;
}
```

What would the most efficient way to change these bytes and write the new header to the output file be?

Comment: Please define "it doesn't seem to work". Can't the modfied header be written? Note that you seem to forget to copy the entire rest of the file ... Also consider using the correct structures to represent the WAV header (you may run into padding problems, but that's a small price to pay for an easier program overall).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A byte array is easiest, if you are sure which bytes you want to change. For example the 4th byte is at `buffer[3]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFSIZE    1024
#define HEADSIZE    44

int main(int argc, char * argv []) {
    int delay;
    size_t bytes;
    FILE * source = NULL;
    FILE * destination = NULL;
    unsigned char buffer[BUFFSIZE];

    if (argc < 4) return 0;         // check enough args
    delay = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (NULL == (source = fopen(argv[2], "rb")))
        return 0;
    if (NULL == (destination = fopen(argv[3], "wb")))
        return 0;

    // copy & alter buffer
    if (HEADSIZE != fread(buffer, 1, HEADSIZE, source))
        return 0;
    buffer[4] = delay;
    buffer[40] = delay;
    if (HEADSIZE != fwrite(buffer, 1, HEADSIZE, destination))
        return 0;

    // copy rest of file
    while ((bytes = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFSIZE, source)) != 0) {
        if (bytes != fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes, destination))
            return 0;
    }
    if (0 == fclose(destination))
        printf("Success\n");
    fclose (source);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of editing bytes in a file, check if it will works for you.

```
int
ChangeHeaderByte(
        const char* fileName,
        unsigned int pos[],
        unsigned int val[],
        unsigned int size
        )
{
  unsigned int i = 0;
  unsigned int temp = 0;
  FILE * fileHandle = fopen(fileName, "r+");
  if (fileHandle == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s : %d : Failed to open file ' %s '\n",
            __func__,__LINE__,fileName);
    return (1);
  }
  for ( i = 0; i < size ; ++i )
  {
    if ( fseek(fileHandle, pos[i] - (unsigned int)1, SEEK_SET) == 0 )
    {
      if ( fread(&temp,sizeof(unsigned int),1,fileHandle) == 1 )
      {
         if ( fseek(fileHandle, pos[i] - (unsigned int)1 , SEEK_SET) == 0 )
         {
             val[i] += temp;
             fwrite(&val[i], sizeof(unsigned int), 1, fileHandle);
         }
         else
         {
             fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s : %d : fseek() failed on file ' %s '\n",
                     __func__,__LINE__,fileName);
             return (1);
         }
      }
      else
      {
          fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s : %d : fread() failed on file ' %s '\n",
                  __func__,__LINE__,fileName);
          return (1);
      }
    } else {
      fprintf(stderr,"Error: %s : %d : fseek() failed on file ' %s '\n",
              __func__,__LINE__,fileName);
      return (1);
    }
  }
  fclose(fileHandle);
  return (0);
}

int main(void)
{
  const unsigned int size = 2;
  char fileName[] = "C:\\Users\\sridhar\\test\\test.wav";
  unsigned int pos[2] = { 4 , 40 };
  unsigned int val[2] = { 123456, 123456 };

  ChangeHeaderByte(fileName,pos,val,size);
  return 0;
}
```